# How to illustrate two graphs?

Tags: python, spyder

I want to show 2 graphs one for the Top 10% income share held and for the bottom 10%, but i am running into the isue that only one grah is illustrated.

A sample of data for the poorest is:
"#""Germany"",""DEU"",""Income share held by lowest 10%"",""SI.DST.FRST.10"","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""",""3.7"",""3.7"",""3.7"",""3.4"",""3.4"",""3.7"",""3.6"",""3.6"",""3.5"",""3.5"",""3.5"",""3.4"",""3.4"",""3.4"",""3.3"",""3.3"",""3.4"",""3.4"",""3.3"",""3.4"",""3.4"",""3.2"",""3.3"",""3.2"",""3.1"",""3.1"",""2.8"",""3.1"",""3.1"","""","""","""","

A sample of data for the wealthiest is:
"Germany,""DEU"",""Income share held by highest 10%"",""SI.DST.10TH.10"","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""","""",""23.2"",""23.1"",""22.8"",""22.9"",""22.7"",""22.3"",""22.4"",""22.3"",""23.1"",""22.9"",""23.9"",""23.7"",""23.9"",""24"",""25.1"",""24.7"",""25.1"",""24.7"",""24"",""24"",""24.5"",""24.4"",""25"",""24.1"",""24.8"",""24.6"",""24.8"",""25.2"",""25.2"","""","""","""","

## My updated Code is:

```
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def read_income_shares(file_name, wealthiest_file_name):
    income_shares = {}
    countries = []
    years = []

    # Read data from the first file
    try:
        with open(file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

            # Skip the first 4 rows
            for _ in range(4):
                next(reader)

            # Read the header to get the years
            header = next(reader)
            years = [int(year.strip('"')) for year in header[4:] if year.strip('"').isdigit()]

            for i, line in enumerate(reader, start=5):
                try:
                    country_name = line[0].strip('"')

                    values = []
                    for val in line[4:]:
                        val = val.replace('""""', '0').replace('"', '').strip()
                        if val and val.replace('.', '').isdigit():
                            values.append(float(val))
                        else:
                            values.append(0)

                    income_shares.setdefault(country_name, {}).update({'Values_Poorest': values})
                    if country_name not in countries:
                        countries.append(country_name)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error in line {i}: {e}")
                    print(f"Line content: {line}")
                    print(f"Warning: Unexpected data structure for {country_name}")

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"Error: File '{file_name}' not found.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: An unexpected error occurred: {e}")

    # Read data from the second file
    try:
        with open(wealthiest_file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            reader = csv.reader(file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

            # Skip the first 4 rows
            for _ in range(4):
                next(reader)

            for i, line in enumerate(reader, start=5):
                try:
                    country_name = line[0].strip('"')

                    values_wealthiest = []
                    values_poorest = []
                    for val in line[4:]:
                        val = val.replace('""""', '0').replace('"', '').strip()
                        if val and val.replace('.', '').isdigit():
                            values_poorest.append(float(val))
                        else:
                            values_poorest.append(0)   
                        if val and val.replace('.', '').isdigit():
                            values_wealthiest.append(float(val))
                        else:
                            values_wealthiest.append(0)
                    if country_name in income_shares:
                        income_shares[country_name]['Values_Poorest'] = values_poorest
                    else:
                        income_shares.setdefault(country_name, {}).update({'Values_Poorest': values_poorest})
                        if country_name not in countries:
                            countries.append(country_name)

                    if country_name in income_shares:
                        income_shares[country_name]['Values_Wealthiest'] = values_wealthiest
                    else:
                        income_shares.setdefault(country_name, {}).update({'Values_Wealthiest': values_wealthiest})
                        if country_name not in countries:
                            countries.append(country_name)

                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error in line {i}: {e}")
                    print(f"Line content: {line}")
                    print(f"Warning: Unexpected data structure for {country_name}")

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"Error: File '{wealthiest_file_name}' not found.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: An unexpected error occurred: {e}")

    return income_shares, countries, years

def plot_income_distribution(countries):
    income_data_one, _, _ = read_income_shares('C:\\Users\\Fabian\\Desktop\\Python Ausarbeitung\\Bravo\\one.txt', 'C:\\Users\\Fabian\\Desktop\\Python Ausarbeitung\\Bravo\\two.txt')
    income_data_two, _, _ = read_income_shares('C:\\Users\\Fabian\\Desktop\\Python Ausarbeitung\\Bravo\\two.txt', 'C:\\Users\\Fabian\\Desktop\\Python Ausarbeitung\\Bravo\\two.txt')

    formatted_countries = []  # Collect formatted country names

    for country in countries:
        # Cleaning up the country name
        country_formatted = country.strip('" \ufeff')
        formatted_countries.append(country_formatted)  # Collect formatted country names

        # Check if data for the country is available in both files
        if country_formatted in income_data_one and country_formatted in income_data_two:
            # Add debugging print statements
            print("Keys for {} in one.txt: {}".format(country_formatted, income_data_one[country_formatted].keys()))
            print("Keys for {} in two.txt: {}".format(country_formatted, income_data_two[country_formatted].keys()))

            # Process the data for one.txt
            if 'Values_Poorest' in income_data_one[country_formatted]:
                income_data_poorest_one = income_data_one[country_formatted]['Values_Poorest']

                # Choose only Years from 1960 to 2022
                years_to_plot = list(range(1960, 2023))

                # Convert values to percentage
                income_data_poorest_percent_one = [val for val in income_data_poorest_one]

                # Filter out values equal to 0
                non_zero_years_poorest_one = [year for year, val in zip(years_to_plot, income_data_poorest_percent_one) if val > 0]
                non_zero_percentages_poorest_one = [val for val in income_data_poorest_percent_one if val > 0]

                # Print the data for debugging
                print("Years for {} in one.txt: {}".format(country_formatted, non_zero_years_poorest_one))
                print("Poorest Percentages for {} in one.txt: {}".format(country_formatted, non_zero_percentages_poorest_one))

                # Plot only if data is available for the year
                plt.plot(non_zero_years_poorest_one, non_zero_percentages_poorest_one, label='{} - Poorest 10%'.format(country_formatted), linestyle='dashed')

            # Process the data for two.txt
            if 'Values_Wealthiest' in income_data_two[country_formatted]:
                income_data_wealthiest_two = income_data_two[country_formatted]['Values_Wealthiest']

                # Choose only Years from 1960 to 2022
                years_to_plot = list(range(1960, 2023))

                # Convert values to percentage
                income_data_wealthiest_percent_two = [val for val in income_data_wealthiest_two]

                # Filter out values equal to 0
                non_zero_years_wealthiest_two = [year for year, val in zip(years_to_plot, income_data_wealthiest_percent_two) if val > 0]
                non_zero_percentages_wealthiest_two = [val for val in income_data_wealthiest_percent_two if val > 0]

                # Print the data for debugging
                print("Years for {} in two.txt: {}".format(country_formatted, non_zero_years_wealthiest_two))
                print("Wealthiest Percentages for {} in two.txt: {}".format(country_formatted, non_zero_percentages_wealthiest_two))

                # Plot only if data is available for the year
                plt.plot(non_zero_years_wealthiest_two, non_zero_percentages_wealthiest_two, label='{} - Wealthiest 10%'.format(country_formatted))

    plt.title('Income Distribution Over Years')
    plt.xlabel('Year')
    plt.ylabel('Income Share (%)')
    plt.ylim(0, 100)  # Set the Y-axis to 0 to 100 percent
    plt.axis([1960, 2022, 0, 100])
    plt.grid(True)

    # Display legend only if data is present.
    if any(formatted_country in income_data_one or formatted_country in income_data_two for formatted_country in formatted_countries):
        plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))  # Move legend outside the plot area

    plt.savefig('income_distribution_plot.png', bbox_inches='tight')  # Save the plot as a PNG file
    plt.show()

# Example call
countries_to_plot = ['"Germany"']
plot_income_distribution(countries_to_plot)
```

Comment: Providing code is good, but  indentation does matter in Python and your code is missing all indentation.. Additionally, your code seems to be commented, but the initial `#` are missing. Your question will be far better received if you fix those two points. As far as I am concerned, I am way too lazy to try to guess and fix the indentation before testing your code, and I know that a good answer generally requires to reproduce the problem and then to text the fix. We love questions containing a [mre]...

Comment: @SergeBallesta I suspect this is copy pasted from Jupiter or some other notebook  which would explain the formatting

Comment: @mousetail: I did not say that OP *intentionally* gave garbage. What I mean is that they know what the correct indentation is while I can only try to guess. Furthermore, I expect many potential answerers to prefere spending time on the resolution of copy/pasteable code than first having to reformat everything. IMHO leaving the question *as is* greatly increases the risk of having no answer. I expected my comment to be received as a kind advice to a new contributor that could not be aware of what a [mre] is. BTW I did not even downvote (for that reason) ;-)

Comment: @SergeBallesta I totally agree with you. I was just pointing out a potential source for this exact type of bad formatting. Of course the question needs to be massively improved before it can be answered

Comment: `Replace """" with 0, then remove double quotes and extract the value from each line` is invalid python code that will make your program crash. Also your code is lacking indentations, which will also prevent your program from running

Comment: @SergeBallesta mousetail Elerium115
Thanks for your advice. Since I am new to the platform and programming in general, I am pleased to take your advice. I hope my edits resolved the issues

Answer (score 0):

I could (partially) reproduce and fix.

First of all, your data file is broken and cannot be processed *in its current formatting* by the csv module. The csv module is great at processing complex data *provided they respect the csv rules*, and here, the quotes are not correctly balanced. As a result, each line is seen as a single quoted field which is not what you expect.

The correct way would be to fix your data files, but as a workaround you can ask the csv module to ignore any quotes and remove them from the data fields, what your code already does. Just open the readers with `quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` (for both files...):

```
...
            reader = csv.reader(file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
...
```

That should be enough to correctly get the expected number of fields per row.

But you have a second problem: the files contains data in the range 0-100, but you multiply them by 100. As a result your data goes in the 0-10000 range and is plotted outside of the figure...

As a workaround, you can just use:

```
        # Convert values to percentage
        income_data_country_percent = [val for val in income_data_country]
        income_data_wealthiest_percent = [val for val in income_data_wealthiest]
```

or directly processed the original values.

But after those two workarounds, I could get a plot.

---

What you should learn from that: your code already has some debugging prints. If you had added more, specially if you had printed the header line, you would have immediately understood that you only got one single field - that is what I have done...

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you have any advice on how to solve the problem with the issue about only one graph showing?
Thanks in advance!